# Firebase linking users across application with unique identifier

Tags: javascript, firebase, uniqueidentifier, firebasesimplelogin

I'm using firebase and my users are set up like this:

```
{
    "firebase-account-123": {
        "users": {
            "simplelogin:1": {
                "properties"{ "name": "john doe", "email": "user@email.com" }
                "children": {
                    "simplelogin:2":{ "name": "user 2", "email": "user2@email.com" },
                }
            },
            "simplelogin:2": {
                "properties"{ "name": "user 2", "email": "user2@email.com", "disabled": false }
            }
        }
}
```

I use `simplelogin:X` and the users `email` across many objects in my database. I know using this to identify my users across different objects is probably a bad move.

At some point I am trying to implement the ability to change emails which means that their simplelogin ID is going to have to change along with every email property that ever linked to their email.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can link users to one another without have to change their data if it changes across the entire platform? I'm thinking somewhere along the lines of a unique identifier for each users. I just don't know how I would implement this.

Comment: `simplelogin:2` **is** a unique identifier for the user. In fact that's why Firebase calls it `auth.uid`. So using this `uid` is not a bad move at all, it's probably the exact opposite: a best practice.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen not when someone changes their email. Then everyplace I've put `simplelogin:2` is irrelevant.

Comment: I can't see myself replacing everything I ever put `simplelogin:2` with. All my logs, etc. There is a lot more than the data thats above.

Comment: I can't see myself regularly changing the email address with which I registered with an application. I **add** mail addresses of course, but I hardly every **change** it.

Comment: I wasn't even aware that you could change your email address in Firebase's simple login, but never used the email+password option of simple login. I'm surprised that they do, because many applications consider email address and identity the same thing.

Comment: A lot of services allow you to change your email and unfortunately I'm going to need to be able to. And firebase doesn't allow you to. it would require deleting the user, creating a new one, and then changing everything that says `simplelogin:2` to whatever the new ID is. So I'm trying to think of a way to create a unique identifier other than id that I can use incase things change. @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: Keep track of their **initial** email address separately and ID on that? Simply auto-generate a sequential ID? There are many ways to come up with user identification. But if Firebase's email/password generates a new uid when the user changes their email address, you won't have a way to wire the new uid to the same user in your data.

Comment: So how many times *have* you changed your email address in an app? I can think of one in the last 10 years, over the span of several hundred accounts...